# Web scraping (Graph Scraping) with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape the below web page.
https://stadt-aachen.e2watch.de/details/objekt/175
I want to get the graph of the page for any specific date. I am not understanding which class should I write for the scraping.
I am using the below code but getting empty strings.

```
import bs4
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r= requests.get('https://stadt-aachen.e2watch.de/details/objekt/175')
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text,"xml")
soup.find_all('div',{'class':'highcharts-container '})
```

Comment: what you want to extract actually ?

Comment: The graph/chart of the given link.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You are using Beatufulsoup for scrapping of web page but graphs are not pure HTML or in other words are rendered from the data. Its not clear from your question whether you are looking for data used to generate the graph or the graph itself which might be in image format.

Comment: I want both the data and the image from the graph.

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm late. But I saw your question today and was very interested in finding out how to get the image out of that website, and I worked out a solution.

1. So first off, the data you want to scrape are `<path>` tags with multiple values inside a `<svg>` tag.The `<svg>` tag can be located by the class.
2. The content is loaded in dynamically through JavaScript. So I tried multiple libraries and solutions but what works best is `Selenium`. Selenium is a Web Driver controlled by Python code.
3. So our plan is to load the content in using selenium and then pass the driver source to BeautifulSoup to scrape it.
4. Then we store the `<svg>` tag inside the variable `html` and pass it to the `screenshot()` method of `hti (Html2Image)`
5. And there you have the graphic from the website. With Selenium you can change the timeframe you want to scrape and get any graphic you want.

```
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from html2image import Html2Image

#Download and place the Driver in the location you want
PATH = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

url = 'https://stadt-aachen.e2watch.de/details/objekt/175'

#This loads the page with the content
driver.get(url)
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(5)

#Then you use BS4 to scrape the driver with the loaded graphic
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)

driver.quit()

#Here you locate the svg tag and store it in a variable html
graphic = soup.findAll('svg', {'class': 'highcharts-root'})
html = str(model[0])

#This open the html2image object and creates a png from the html in the size of the svg
hti = Html2Image()
hti.screenshot(html_str=html, size=(970,600), save_as='output.png')
```

Let me know if you have questions or other problems with scraping.